# Play audio to two different Audiodevices simultaneously with Naudio

Tags: c#, audio, device, naudio

I'm trying to figure out how to play music to two different audiodevices at the same time.

What I've done is to create a class that makes life easier for me when programming with Naudio, it has play mp3 & wav's, pause, stop etc etc.

What I'd love to have is the ability to chose what playback device the audiostream should be outputted to. Is there some way I can incorporate it like this:

Play to: Realtek HD audio 2nd output and Speakers (if it was plugged in)

[image]

Here's the "Play" function I created:

```
public void Play(string Searchpath, int Time = 0)
    {
        DisposeWave();
        string FileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(Searchpath);
        if (FileExtension == (".mp3"))
        {
            NAudio.Wave.WaveStream pcmstream = NAudio.Wave.WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(new NAudio.Wave.Mp3FileReader(Searchpath));
            stream = new NAudio.Wave.BlockAlignReductionStream(pcmstream);
        }
        else if (FileExtension == (".wav"))
        {
            NAudio.Wave.WaveStream pcmstream = new NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32(new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader(Searchpath));
            stream = new NAudio.Wave.BlockAlignReductionStream(pcmstream);
        }

        output = new NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut();
        output.Init(stream);
        output.Play();

        Playbackstate = PlaybackState.Playing;
    }
```

Is there some page I can read up on this at?

Thank you

Comment: I hope you're not intending to synchronize playback on two devices simultaneously, as this is nearly impossible.  First, you have the problem of sample rate, but then you have the issue that separate devices do not have a common clock and will inevitably drift apart.  ASIO4ALL attempts to compensate for this across multiple devices, and makes them appear as one.  That is your best bet, but would require you to implement ASIO support.

Comment: No, no synchronization. Just the ability to play two, maybe different songs on two different devices at once.

Comment: Use the Device-Property of the output.